# libgit2sharp get next version changes

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

Using the code from this answer I can checkout a specific version of the codebase just fine.

[How do I get a previous version of a file with libgit2sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450342/how-do-i-get-a-previous-version-of-a-file-with-libgit2sharp)

I then further want to get the next version after that.  I get an error when getting the next version.

> 19691 conflicts prevent checkout

What is the best way to get the changes from the next version into the same directory ?  Perhaps do a get first to a temp directory and then copy replace over the first, is there a better way ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying about why you don't want to use `Force`?

Comment: I realize I mis-understood the Force flag.  Here is what I want to do, get a specific version to tmp, then get the next version into the same directory ( but only the delta files between the versions ).  In other words I do not want a fresh get for the next version, only the files that have changed between the two.

Comment: Checkout will do that for you.  It will only update the files that changed between the two versions.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is to get code using the answer from this question.

[How do I get a previous version of a file with libgit2sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450342/how-do-i-get-a-previous-version-of-a-file-with-libgit2sharp)

Then do a diff in the main repository to figure out the changed files for the next commit.  With that list I can get only the changed or added files and remove deleted files from the first get.  This works pretty fast when dealing with repositories with a lot of files in them.